# Dynamically change the CSS, Logos on the osTicket site based on who logs in

Tags: php, osticket

I have 3 Organisation in my `osTicket Version 1.10`. I have associated users in each organization. I need to change the CSS and Logo's when user `logins` into the `osTicket` based on the organization which has been associated with them.

How can I achieve it? Searched whether this option is available in Admin panel, But it does not have.

Comment: Put your code here which you have tried.

Comment: Your question is too broad. This can be achieved in many ways thus you should choose an approach and start, and if you face any difficulties, you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Gufran / Nima - i am New to osTicket and i am looking for documentation / guide to start with.